# Validate URL without http, https and www

Tags: php

I have an input box where user can enter their domain. I want to make sure the domain should be like that:

example.com
hello.com
okay.com

NOT

> [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
> https://www.hello.com
> https://okay.com

I mean no **http**, **https** and **www** at the beginning of the domain.

So far I got this:

```
} elseif( !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z. ]+$/', $domain) ) {
    $output['message'][] = 'Your domain should be start with http, https or www but can contain (.)com';
}
```

How can I improve this **preg_match** function to get the desire validation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using parse\_url in php, how do we check whether input is a url or just a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046587/using-parse-url-in-php-how-do-we-check-whether-input-is-a-url-or-just-a-string)

Comment: `^\w+.com$` https://regex101.com/r/ydoYEq/1

Comment: @shingo do you mean this `!preg_match('^\w+.\w+$', $domain)`

Comment: `and www at the beginning of the domain` -- please clarify why subdomains are not permitted?

Comment: _"Your domain should be contain only characters."_ - that is quite a misleading error message, when your pattern actually allows not only for dots, but for _spaces_ for some reason as well. And do you really want to reject any user input here, if their domain name would contain digits or hyphens ...?

Comment: I will change the message @CBroe but I need only domain name without the http, https and www at the beginning.

Comment: This regex will be incorrect because it can also pass `......`. Better to use parse_url() and filter url functions.

Comment: @shingo That regex fails for `s3.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url) - if you just want the domain without a protocol, why not strip it from user input before using it

Comment: @AD7six no, I just  want to modify my current `preg_match` function so that user can't input http, https or www

Comment: Why are you insisting on using a regex when there are specific functions for validating URL's?

Comment: @Shibbir You can't be stern with your approach.

Comment: @AD7six which question I should tell you (why)?

Comment: I think you don't understand what I Need.

Comment: @Shibbir Is nicedev's example `s3.amazonaws.com` also to be considered?

Comment: My application needs this validation. So if anyone can help me that would be better.

Comment: @shingo Yes, it will be accepted.

Comment: And how about `example.123`? Is that a valid input?

Comment: @shingo Yes, I just don't want the http, https or www from the begging of the string.

Comment: So `http.example.com` is not valid too? I mean no `://` but `http` is at the beginning.

Comment: But `123` is not [a valid top-level domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071279/number-in-the-top-level-domain)...

Comment: @shingo only `example.com` will be valid.

Comment: _"I think you don't understand what I Need"_ - and I am not too sure _you_ understand what you need :-) _"I just don't want the http, https or www from the begging of the string"_ - that alone would not be a reason to reject domain names that contain digits or hyphens then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `/^(?!(www|http|https)\.)\w+(\.\w+)+$/`

It matches

> example.com
> hello.com
> okay.com
> example.123
> 1.example.com.cn
> s3.amazonaws.com

It doesn't match

> [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
> https://www.hello.com
> https://okay.com
> http.example.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what about `httpyahoo.com` or `httpsyahoo.com` or `wwwyahoo.com` ?

Comment: They match, if you don't want to match these domains, just remove the first dot.

Comment: I did it but not working. I enter this text `httpyahoo.com` but showing me my validation error. Its should be passed.

Comment: I am using this `! preg_match('/^(?!(www|http|https))\w+(.\w+)+$/', $domain)`

Comment: Sorry, I missed backslashes before dot.

Comment: I fear this will haunt you in the future @shingo as an example of the problem with providing answers which exactly match the request but are a poor (or entirely inappropriate) solution for the job :). That regex arbitrarily prevents some [valid](https://www.namecheap.com/domains/registration/results/?domain=https) [domains](https://www.namecheap.com/domains/registration/results/?domain=www) and subdomains whist allowing junk like `not.a.domain` to pass.

Comment: @AD7six but op had confirmed in the comments above that `https.example.com` is invalid (valid domain) and  `example.123` is valid (not a domain)